# How to get bit size of an enum, or of a struct bit field?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to access the "bit size" of a struct [bit field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), or the bit range of an [enum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)?

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
auto bitsizeof() {
    return sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT;
}

struct Foo {
    unsigned vi : 6;
};

enum Bar { zero = 0, seven = 7 }; // bit-range is 3.

int main() {
    std::cout << "char is        " << bitsizeof<char>() << "\n";
    std::cout << "int is         " << bitsizeof<int>() << "\n";
    std::cout << "long double is " << bitsizeof<long double>() << "\n";

    // Aww.
    std::cout << "Foo::vi is     " << bitsizeof<decltype(std::declval<Foo>().vi)>() << " (ought to be 6)\n";

    // Aww.
    std::cout << "Bar is         " << bitsizeof<Bar>() << " (ought to be 3)\n";
}

/* OUTPUT
char is        8
int is         32
long double is 128
Foo::vi is     32 (ought to be 6)
Bar is         32 (ought to be 3)
*/
```

If there is not a general way to retrieve the bit size of those things at compile time — or calculate it at runtime — my workaround is `constexpr std::size_t Bar_bitsize = 3;` and `constexpr std::size_t Foo_vi_bitsize = 6;` and calculate them manually and hard-code them.  But that feels brittle.

**UPDATE**: additional information.

In C++ (not in C) an `enum` that does not specify backing storage has a **bit range** based on its enum members.  It is **undefined behavior** to set an enum to a value outside of its bit range.

Comment: By default, the size of an `enum` is the size of an `int` unless you specify an underlying type. C++ does not allows to get information of a type or object at bit level.

Comment: how could an addressable object have a size of 3 bits?

Comment: @Eljay Well your output clearly shows that your compiler uses 32 bits for storage of `Bar`.   While you should not set an emun to a value outside of its range, actual memory is a whole number of bytes.

Comment: @Phil1970 • You are correct, the actual memory is a whole number of bytes.  I'm interested in (programmatically) calculating the payload **bits** of the `enum` and not the padding/fallow bits, rather than the `sizeof` in bytes of the actual memory.